# Pasar datos a un Web Form con asp.net en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, webforms

Hola disculpen que los moleste, tengo una consulta dado que he tenido varios problemas pasando datos desde .aspx.cs a .aspx y quería preguntar cual es la mejor forma de pasar datos entre esos 2 archivos.

yo lo que siempre hago es en la clase hija de **System.Web.UI.Page** creo mis properties de los objetos a mostrar y le ingreso datos en el load, luego con un foreach en el .aspx muestro toda la información necesaria, pero siempre me genera muchos inconvenientes.

este es el archivo .aspx.cs

```
    public partial class Motos : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public List<Moto> lMoto { get; set; }


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lMoto = agregarMotos(); //Este es un metodo que trae una lista de motos desde BD, pudiendo venir llena o vacía 
            
            if (lMoto == null) this.lMoto = new List<Moto>();
        }
```

este es el archivo .aspx

```
              <tbody>
                    <% foreach (controlador.Moto item in lMoto)
                       { %>
                        <tr>
                          <th><% = item.ID %></th>
                          <th><% = item.modelo.nombreMarca %></th>
                          <th><% = item.modelo.nombreModelo %></th>
                          <th><% = item.patente %></th>
                          <td><% = item.cilindrada %></td>
                          <td>
                              <a href="?IDMarca=<% = item.ID %>">
                                  <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                              </a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                    <% } %>
              </tbody>
```

De esta forma siempre me tira un error diciendo que la referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

ante eso que se puede hacer?
yo averigüe un par de soluciones como usar un ViewBag pero no me quedo claro la implementación del mismo y si en mi caso lo podría llegar a utilizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para linkar datos de una lista desde el archivo .cs en la vista, una opción que te puede funcionar bastante bien, es el elemento [Repeater](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater?view=netframework-4.8)

Teniendo en cuenta que estás colocándolo en una tabla, tu código quedaría así:

En el archivo .aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptMotos">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Marca</th>
                        <th>Modelo</th>
                        <th>Patente</th>
                        <th>Cilindrada</th>
                        <th>...</th>
                        
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><%#Eval("Id") %></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("Marca") %></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("Modelo") %></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("Patente") %></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("Cilindrada") %></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>


            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Dentro de los Eval tendrás que poner el nombre exacto del atributo del objeto.

Archivo .cs:

```
public partial class Motos : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<Moto> lMoto { get; set; }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lMoto = agregarMotos(); //Este es un metodo que trae una lista de motos desde BD, pudiendo venir llena o vacía 
        
        RptMotos.DataSource = lMoto;
        RptMotos.Databind();
    }
```